# db.insert only stores auto incremented id in database

Tags: android, sqlite

db.insert function inserts only an auto incremented ID in the table and nothing else though I get values from activity edit texts. Rest of the cells of table row remain empty

Here is my code:

```
public class SHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static final String dbName = "School";
    static final String studentTable = "Student";
    static final String colName = "Name";
    static final String colPassword = "Password";
    public static final int dbVersion=1;

    public SHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+studentTable+"("+colID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+colName+" TEXT,"+colPassword+" TEXT);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + studentTable);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void add(StudentData studentdata) 
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(colName, StudentData.getName()); 
        values.put(colPassword, StudentData.getPassword());
        db.insert(studentTable, null, values);
        db.close();
    }


}

public class StudentData {

    private static String name;
    private static String password;

    public StudentData() {
        super();
    }

    public StudentData(String name,String password) {
        super();

        StudentData.name = name;
        StudentData.password = password;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        StudentData.name = name;
    }

        public static String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        StudentData.password = password;
    }
}

public class stoActivity extends Activity {

     SHelper db = new SHelper(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sto);

        final EditText fullname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fullName);
        final EditText password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        final String fullname=fullname.getText().toString();
        final String password=password.getText().toString();

        Button registerbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);      
        registerbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v){

            db.add(new StudentData(fullname,password));  

           Intent it=new Intent(stoActivity.this,otherActivity.class);
           stoActivity.this.startActivity(it);   
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_register, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it throw any exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's your issue:

```
public void add(*StudentData studentdata) 
    {
        ...    
        values.put(colName, *StudentData.getName()); 
        values.put(colPassword, *StudentData.getPassword());
        ...
    }
```

Can you see it? Your statement is referring to the wrong part of the signature. you need to change the `StudentData` in the body of your method to lower case `studentdata` to match what is being passed to the method as a parameter. This illegal behavior went by compiled because you have the static modifier in places where i'm not sure is necessary, ex. the `getName()` and `getPassword()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

create table with AutoIncrement key, so change method onCreate to the following:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+studentTable+"("+colID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+colName+" TEXT,"+colPassword+" TEXT);");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting any value for the column you have declared as primary Key.

Answer (score 0):

It´s just an assumtion, but I had similar problems if I wanted to save data inside db. In your onCreate-Method at db.execSQL, You got a blank after comma --> "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ". I know that SQLite is very sensitive with such kind of input, You have to look exactly at blanks, commas or any other input.